# Laravel Controller api and web middleware

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, middleware

I have a controller which I wish to use for both web routes and API routes to save duplicating the code.

Each method has their own way of authenticating through the auth middlewares.

If I comment out the web middleware the api will work and vice-versa.

When I have both of these in I cannot access the controller.

How can I have both checks but allow access to the controller if ONE of the middleware conditions are met?

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        // need this for api route only
        $this->middleware('auth:api');

        // need this for web route only
        $this->middleware('auth:web');

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is bad design, but you can use like this. In this case, first successful guard authorise user.

For avoid duplicates - you must move code to service layer in inject services in controllers

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api,web');
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it works for the api route but not the web route

Comment: web guard itself working? because middleware code check all guards - and auth user with first successful - see Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::authenticate()

Answer (score 1):

Managed to wrap this in an auth guard condition, leaving here in case anyone finds this in the future

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        if (!Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
            $this->middleware('auth:web');
        } else {
            $this->middleware('auth:api');
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }
```